# why the right content won't stack directly under the next div?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

How can I make the `.right-content` stack under the div above it?
I'm using `flex` and `flex-basis` to make this layout and what I realized is **If the `left-content` is too long**, the second div `.right-content` (social icons) will gets pushed down and wont stack under the first div holding same class. Tried to make the code as short as I can.

[image: Screenshot showing what I'm trying to do]

[You can see this link](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/KobOjj)

Or check the code below:

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid
}

.wrap {
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 800px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.content {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  align-items: flex-start;
  width: 100%;
}

.left-content {
  flex-basis: 65%;
}

.right-content {
  flex-basis: 33%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="wrap__main">
    <div class="content">
      <div class="left-content">
        <div class="content">
          <h2>This is header</h2>
          <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. </p>
        </div>
        <div class="content">
          <h2>This is header</h2>
          <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. </p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="right-content">
        <form>
          <input type="text" placeholder="Name">
          <input type="text" placeholder="email">
          <input type="submit" value="Submit">
        </form>
      </div>
      <div class="left-content">
        <div class="content">
          <h2>This is header</h2>
          <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. </p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="right-content">
        <a href="http://www.facebook.com/"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/22/f5f" width="22" alt="Facebook" /></a>
        <a href="http://www.facebook.com/"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/22/f5f" width="22" alt="Facebook" /></a>
        <a href="http://www.facebook.com/"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/22/f5f" width="22" alt="Facebook" /></a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: you need to change the layout .. make a colum for your left content and another one for the right content

Comment: I tried that but then the `flex-basis` wont work? @TemaniAfif

Comment: it will :) you simply need to nest flex layout and apply flex-basis on the upper one

Comment: So main container will be `row` and `display: flex` then nested container will be `display: flex` and `column` and add `flex-basis` @TemaniAfif

Comment: yes that's it ... and you keep the actul flex-basis on the main containers (left and right) .. by the way you may not need flex inside them as by default block element are width:100%

Comment: I thought about that but the problem is: I cant change the last container's position it will always be with the form while if i want to move it to the end of the main container I might need to manipulate the DOM with JS @TemaniAfif

Comment: no you can use order property of flexbox to reorder if you want